# HTML encoded characters and CDATA being lost after converting xml String to Document object then back to String. Is there any way to avoid?

Tags: java, xml, dom, encoding, cdata

Lets say we have an xml like so:

```
<item>
   <![CDATA[abc]]>
</item>
```

I have a method `convertStringToDocument` that converts this `String xmlString` into a Document (org.w3c.dom.Document). In order to digitally sign the xml.

```
public static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlString) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = generateDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
        return document;
    } 
    catch ...
    }
    return null;
}

public static DocumentBuilder generateDocumentBuilder() {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(false);
        dbf.setIgnoringComments(false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        return db;
    } 
    catch ...
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, when converting this `Document` back into a string, the `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tag is lost. The same this occurs for html encoded characters like `&#8211;`. Below is how `Document` objects are converted back to string:

```
public static String convertDocumentToString(Document doc, boolean omitXmlDeclaration) {
    try {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        t.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
        return sw.toString();
    } 
    catch ...
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is it possible to convert the `String xmlString` into a `Document` and then back into a `String` without losing `<![CDATA[...]]>` tags or HTML encoding?

Comment: using your code, I was unable to reproduce your situation... what java version are you using?

Comment: I should have been more clear,
`<item><![CDATA[abc]]></item>`

becomes: `<item>abc</item>`

I have java 1.8.0_91